# How can I use in ASP.NET href and css with meta:resourceKey

Tags: asp.net, css

QUESTION 1: I want to use a specific url if the user is visiting the page with a specific language

```
<div  class="homepage-footer">
                            <img id="imgHomepageFooter" runat="server"
                                 usemap="#videomap" alt="Video" meta:resourcekey="imgHomepageFooter" />

                            <map name="videomap">
                                 <area shape="rect" id="youtubeVideo" coords="43,0,560,56" href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q2QsjVCapjs" target="_blank" alt="Youtube Video"
                                  />
                            </map>
                        </div>
```

I need to replace href with a specific url because the for spanish peoplo the video could be in youtube, but for english in www.google.com how could I redirect the page depending on my metaresources

---

QUESTION 2: I am using css for this page, but if I put the css separatly I don't know how to use inside the meta:resourcekey, so I put it as a part of my page and still I don't know the combination, I need to replace the background-image with a specific resources if I am using a specific language(that is the scenario)

```
style type="text/css">
    div.countdown-image 
    {
        background-image: url(../images/homepage/countdown-image-ENG-2015.png);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        height: 150px;
    }

</style>

<!-- Countdown -->
<div id="countdown-container">
     <div class="countdown-image">
        <div id="countdown-timer" class="countdown-bottom">
        </div>
     </div>
    <input id="DeadlineDateTime" value="" runat="server" type="hidden" />
</div>
```

Comment: Could you be more specific: what language do you use because Classic ASP methods will be useless in ASP.NET or MVC and other way around.

Comment: That is ASP.NET not MVC

Answer (score 1):

One option is to handle the request server-side changing the values of the HTML controls as you need, based on the user's language. The answer of @All Blond follows this approach.

Another option is do the same but client-side, using JavaScript (jQuery recommended). You can locate the relevant HTML objects (using the jQuery selector $) and replace / update its properties based on the user's language as you need.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on C#/ASP.net side then basically you should use in your main or onInit function

```
  string  userLang = HttpContext.Request.UserLanguages.ToString();
   // I would prefer do switch based on userLang  but it could be as simple as:
  if (userLang = "en-CA")
    {

      //  here you can do switch for your content anyway you want to.
      // including changing your assign CSS or images - as a string or InnnerHTML content
      // it is depend on solution you implement in your code.

    }
```

Values "en-CA" you can look up on Google for example for each needed language.